# Passing POST request by AJAX, Django problem

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-views

my view is :

```
def creating_profile(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        array = request.POST.get('nums')
        print(request.POST.get('nums'))
    else:
        print('it's not ajax')
```

my js:

```
const RegisterForm = document.forms["RegisterForm"];
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
let nums = [1, 2, 3]
RegisterForm.addEventListener('submit', () => {
    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken },
        url: '/account/creating-profile/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { nums: nums },
        success: function (data) {
            //
        }
    });
```

but it returns `None` the result of `print(request.POST.get('nums'))`, I would be glad if someone help me about this issue

update :
[image]

Comment: in $.ajax you are missing `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @TusharD also None

Comment: looks like request.POST will not able to access Non-form data in HTTP requests (json data), you  will need to access reqeust.body attr

refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#non-form-data-in-http-requests

try ` print(json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not extremely familliar with Ajax, but whenever I try to pass data from a form to my view, I use FormData:

```
form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("RegisterForm"))
```

This adds all fields of the form in a dictionnary, where you can access values by the field name. You can add on top of it using .append()

Then in your request you can use

```
fetch("/account/creating-profile/", {
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: form_data,
        method:"POST"})
```

And retrieve it in your view using

```
nums = request.POST["nums"]
```

Edit :

Your JS would look like this :

```
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
let nums = [1, 2, 3]
myHeaders = new Headers()
myHeaders.append("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
form_data = new FormData(document.forms["RegisterForm"]);
form_data.append("nums", nums) // <-- Here you can add anything to the form data using form_data.append("Key", value)

fetch("/account/creating-profile/", {
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: form_data,
        method:"POST"})
```

Doing so will POST on your server twice if you don't prevent default POST from happening, you can prevent it doing this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#RegisterForm").submit(function(){
        return false
    })
})
```

or by using an event listenner and preventDefault (see docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: where should i add data ? like that array inside my js code

Comment: Edited with more details

Comment: give me MultiValueDictKeyError at /account/creating-profile/
'nums' :(

Comment: hey it works now, but i get two query request, one from fetch with nums, the second i guess from html form without nums. how can i fet only one?

Comment: Edited for more details. You can use preventDefaults or return False with Ajax, as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getlist()` method to access list object in from **POST** like this

```
def creating_profile(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        array = request.POST.getlist('nums')
        print(array)# this will return [1, 2, 3]
    else:
        print('it's not ajax')
```

and about  ***MultiValueDictKeyError*** it occurs if data is not present in your `request.POST['key']` than raise ***MultiValueDictKeyError*** solution is
use `get()` method it will return ***None*** if given key does not have any value and will not raise any exception.

> *A data to be sent to the server. It can be JSON object, string or
> array.*

```
 data: { "nums": nums }
```

check this [doc.](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method)

Comment: unfortunately, It returns [ ]

Comment: did you tried to change your data  to ***JSON*** format like this  ```data: { "nums": nums }```

Comment: yes i did, it when i print whole of request it only show the html form values has sent

Comment: Hello @MehranBahrami can you show your whole ajax call code including opening and closing script tag

Comment: Hi, This is the whole of ajax i have in my js file

Comment: Hello @MehranBahrami try like this ```data: JSON.stringify({ "nums": nums }),```

Comment: also empty [ ], no need to show my html ?

Comment: Hello @MehranBahrami would you like to connect on anydesk ?

Comment: that would be amazing

Comment: Okay, give me your anydesk Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236725/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-mehran-bahrami).